# Correct way to catch exception in python method and raising same exception to caller method

Tags: python, python-3.x

what is the best pythonic way to raising exception inside method.

My python method detectes few  exception, I should raise same detected exception to caller method, so that I can catch and handle in caller method.

```
import sys
def raise_func_exception():
    try:
        a = 1 / 0
    except Exception as e:
        raise e
    
    return a

# calling python function
try:
    print(raise_func_exception())
except Exception as e:
    print("Error: ", e)
    sys.exit(-1)

print("program operation method is completed")
sys.exit()
```

Above code is working fine, but is it right way of pythonnic or any other way I need to consider?

I feel i it is redudant, my use case is

```
 1. I have common.py or module
 2. program-1 called common.py, it catches exception raised by common.py and It performs other operations based an exceptions.
 3. program-2 too called common.py, it catches exception raised by common.py,  program-2 terminates its run due to exception. 
 
 # As per my use case I cannot able handle everything in main method, only caller methods knows what has to be done in case of any exceptions.
```

I reffered many stack overflow questions, I did not find right answer, might be weak at searching. I got how to raise, catch and raise exceptions, but not similar to catching and raising same exception.

Comment: Catching an exception and then raising the same exception seems redundant if you are not doing anything else in the `except` block, not catching the exception in the first place would have the same effect. Are you asking how to raise a different exception in `except`?

Comment: I have common python functions, I do not want to handle in method itself, I want to handle from caller side, example: program 1 is calling common method and it detects exception, based on exception it performs other operations, in program 2 also calls common method, but program terminates due to exception.

Comment: @lain Added all details question

Comment: Also note: If you want to reraise the same exception as if you'd never caught it, just do `raise`, no argument. A bare `raise` in an `except` block reraises the caught exception. It's common to do something like this to log immediately when the exception occurs, but otherwise let it bubble up unaltered.